# input responsive width bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, input

I want to change from 100% width of input, to 50%, and, have it at the center and responsive, when I resize the window of browser.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>teste</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <form class="form">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1">
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What CSS have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#exampleInputEmail1 {
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ygvhs676/1/

Answer (score -1):

If you place your CSS file after bootstrap CSS file in html head section it should overwrite width and I think you can remove !important then. Snippet is a bit inconvenient for that.

```css
.form-control{
  margin: auto;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  width:50% !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <form class="form">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1">
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: There is no need for `left: 0;` or `right: 0;`, and in his example his `style.css` is linked after Bootstrap, so you can safely remove `!important`. You may also want to add a `min-width: 100px;` or similar, to prevent the input getting too small on mobile devices.